# Place a Map in JPanel or JFrame in Java using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maps

Please can someone help me to place a map like google maps or bing maps or even other maps that you can suggest in a JPanel or JFrame.

I tried the JxMapKit but it does not work and does not display the openstreetmap in the JFrame. It gives an error like it can't get the tile in johny.se something.....

Is it still possible to use the JxMapviewer? because i want to use this map for gps tracking application.

thanks...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [MCVE] version of you code

Comment: Do you want a still picture, or an interactive area with panning and zooming like maps.google.com displays?  A still picture can be obtained by passing a URL to an ImageIcon constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Terramenta](https://bitbucket.org/teamninjaneer/terramenta/wiki/Home), that's a java based high-end extendable map solution, should be perfect for a GPS tracker application. If you're looking for a simpler solution you could have a look at [JXMapViewer2](https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2)

Hope this helps